# scipy.misc missing

Tags: python, scipy

I just installed scipy (through `easy_install scipy`), but for some reason `scipy.misc` is missing.

Take a look at this:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy
<module 'scipy' from '/home/boda/python-2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/scipy/__init__.pyc'>
>>> scipy.misc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'misc'
```

Does anyone know what could have happened? There are literally 0 Google results for `scipy.misc` missing. I seem to be the first person to whom this has happened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The modules inside scipy aren't accessible as attributes of the base scipy package.  You need to do `import scipy.misc` or `from scipy import misc`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I didn't know that modules inside scipy aren't accessible as attributes of the base scipy package.

Comment: That is strange.  On my python, that `scipy.misc` module _is_ accessible after `import scipy`.  I'm just using the apt version in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @wim: Interesting.  I see the same behavior as the OP (using Python 2.7 on Windows).